# Best way to load an external page into the current one with Webkit/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, webkit

I would like to load a complete HTML page into the current one using standard web technologies on an iPad web app (no framework like Sencha, etc.)

I have a content page, and an article page. I want to load the article page (including javascript/CSS for this specific page) into a new div and animate the transition (sliding) but it does not seem to work.

Using jQuery load function, the CSS/JS is not perfectly loaded and it works only on Chrome (not on the iPad). Is there a better way to do so?

**CSS:**

```
#content-container {
}

#article-container {
position: absolute;
left: @defaultWidth;

width: 100%;
height: 100%;

background-color: @darkGreyColour;

-webkit-transition: left 1s ease-in; 
}

#content-container.animate {
left: -100%;
}

#article-container.animate {
    left: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
function animateTransition(event) {
    $('#article-container').load('/ #main', function() {
        console.log("Animating...");
        $('#content-container').addClass('animate');
        $('#article-container').addClass('animate');
    });
}
```

Comment: what `doesn't work`? do you have a display problem, which one? what is the generated code? what is the `load` code?

Comment: The page loads the CSS/Javascript of the external page does not so I get a weird result. Do I have to use jQuery getScript function to load the JS, and a home made one for the CSS or should it do it automatically?

Comment: I do not understand fully what you are trying to achieve, but could it be that you are running into cross site scripting problems? Maybe a jsfiddle would clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an `<iframe>` to load a full HTML page.  Using jQuery's .load() to load a portion of a full html page (ex. `$("#myElement").load("/index.html #main")` ) only loads the html in that portion of the document, so it won't load the js / css that's defined in other portions of the article page.  You can read more about the issue in the 'Loading Page Fragments' section of [jQuery's .load API Page](http://api.jquery.com/load/#).

Using an `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="theArticle.html">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Using jQuery and .load() to load the article into the `<div>`:

```
function animateTransition(event) {
    // load the html contained in the tag with id of #main
    $('#article-container').load('myArticle.html #main', function() {
        // load the css
        $('head').load('myCSS.css', function() {
            // load the js
            $.getScript('myScript.js', function() {
                console.log("Animating...");
                $('#content-container').addClass('animate');
                $('#article-container').addClass('animate');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the iPad does not really like iFrames, and I implemented a solution pretty similar to the one you have described!