# Adapting load() code

Tags: jquery

I was trying to adapt the code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557386/best-way-to-load-an-external-page-into-the-current-one-with-webkit-jquery), which solution was:

```
function animateTransition(event) {
    // load the html contained in the tag with id of #main
    $('#article-container').load('myArticle.html #main', function() {
        // load the css
        $('head').load('myCSS.css', function() {
            // load the js
            $.getScript('myScript.js', function() {
                console.log("Animating...");
                $('#content-container').addClass('animate');
                $('#article-container').addClass('animate');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

... coming up with my own version:

```
<div id="menu_aEmpresa"
     onclick="$('#mainContent')
              .load('aEmpresa_pt.html #aEmpresa_mainContent > *', function(){
                $('head').load('css/aEmpresa.css'); // load the css
                $.getScript('js/aEmpresa.js'); // load the js
              });">
</div>
```

Basically I want to load the css and js files that are referred inside the external file (aEmpresa_pt.html) the same time I load it's content.
This syntax doesn't work, though. Help, please?

Thank you.

Pedro

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way you should code using jquery.

You should separate your html code with your js/jquery code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu_aEmpresa"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#menu_aEmpresa').on('click',function(){
            $('#mainContent')
              .load('aEmpresa_pt.html #aEmpresa_mainContent > *', function(){
                $('head').load('css/aEmpresa.css'); // load the css
                $.getScript('js/aEmpresa.js'); // load the js
             });">
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx for the swift response. The problem persists though, the content loads fine but with no css and js applied. File names and paths are all good (had to put a "/" before the folder though)... any ideas?